# VisionFive2 PHY layer register's base address

Tags: driver, nic

I'm developing a NIC driver for a colage assingment using the EPOS operating system, gave by the Professor. And i haven't been able to locate the ethernet phy layer base address for the VisionFive2 board. I've already looked at the VisionFive2 datasheet, ehternet port and developing guide, the linux ethernet driver for the board and couldn't locate this address, does anyone know where can i find it?

Help with developing de NIC driver for the VisionFive2 board